# MongoDB: Is it possible to set the case of a BsonElement by default?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using the Mongodb official driver and I want to set by default the naming of the elements to lower case to avoid code like this:

```
public class Localization
{
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(ObjectIdGenerator))]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [BsonRequired]
    [BsonElement("country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
```

In this sample I want that by default the element name be "country" not "Country" aka lower case. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A small update since the BsonClassMap.RegisterConventions is marked as obsolete

```
var camelCaseConventionPack = new ConventionPack { new CamelCaseElementNameConvention() };
ConventionRegistry.Register("CamelCase", camelCaseConventionPack, type => true);
```

Comment: Also, make sure you add this convention before you register types with BsonClassMap, or you'll have a bad time!

Answer (score 3):

```cs
var conventions = new ConventionProfile();
conventions.SetElementNameConvention(new CamelCaseElementNameConvention());

BsonClassMap.RegisterConventions(conventions, t => true);
```

[MongoDB CSharp Driver Serialization Tutorial](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-Conventions)

Comment: While I can appreciate the unacceptance of my answer if this is truly better, the question specifically mentioned lower case, not camel case.  Since a lower case convention isn't included, you'd need to write your own (hence my answer).  If he legitimately wants camel case for his fields, then we should edit the question to reflect that for future lookers.

Comment: The answer is out of date. The suggested solution uses obsolete driver methods.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can create a ConventionProfile and override the ElementName convention.  See the docs here for how to do it: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial#CSharpDriverSerializationTutorial-Conventions